titlesec package doesn't work in lyx
im using lyx and im trying to remove the section number and keep in in the TOC, i've tried using the \titleformat command but it doesn't work at all and changes nothing, here is my preamble
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\reversemarginpar
\sloppy

%%%%% FONTS %%%%%%
%\sectionfont{\Huge\centering}
\subsectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

\fancyfoot[C]{\strut\xrfill[3pt]{0.4pt}\hspace{-1.5pt}( \thepage{} )\hspace{-2,5pt}\xrfill[3pt]{0.4pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

it doesn't matter if I use the package sectsty or not, it's like the package titlesec doesn't work at all
this is a small example
%% LyX 2.4.1 created this file.  For more info, see https://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David Libre}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{FreeSans}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm,headheight=0cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\reversemarginpar
\sloppy

%%%%% FONTS %%%%%%
%\sectionfont{\Huge\centering}
\subsectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

\fancyfoot[C]{\strut\xrfill[3pt]{0.4pt}\hspace{-1.5pt}( \thepage{} )\hspace{-2,5pt}\xrfill[3pt]{0.4pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\small\(\bullet\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\section{חלק א}

\subsection{שדגשדגשג}

שגשדגשדגדגשד
\end{document}


Please complete your sample code by adding a line \documentclass{...} and some text between \begin{document} and \end{document}, such that your code is compilable and demonstrates your problem. Expecially the document class is central in understanding what's going on.

I've added the output of lyx

I don't think sectsty and titlesec should be used together. So if you need titlesec your numbering issues then you need to use it for the fonts as well. You're also using bidi which redefines all sorts of things, and will certainly complicate matters. (I'm not suggesting you not use it, just making an observation about its use.)
